# How to fix aesthetically glitchy Kivy scaling on windows?

Tags: python, windows, kivy

Is there a way to make scaling Kivy windows aesthetically pleasing?

When one scales a window in Kivy by default, it appears that the contents of the window stretch with the scaling of the window, resulting in a pixelated mess. Only upon releasing the window does it render the contents properly.

Warping Example

[image]

I'm using running this in windows. Full pip list included

Here's my code if you want to run it. Try scaling the window, you should see smearing (if it's not a problem with my kivy install)

### main.py

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
    display = ObjectProperty(None)

    def calculate(self, calculation):
        if calculation:
            try:
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "you MORON"

class CalculatorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()

calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()
```

### calculator.kv

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32

<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "7"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "8"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "9"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "+"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "4"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "5"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "6"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "-"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "*"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "AC"
            on_press: entry.text = ""
        CustButton:
            text: "0"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "="
            on_press: calculator.calculate(entry.text)
        CustButton:
            text: "/"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
```

### pip list results

```
absl-py             0.6.1
astor               0.7.1
certifi             2018.11.29
chardet             3.0.4
cycler              0.10.0
docutils            0.14
future              0.17.1
gast                0.2.0
graphviz            0.10.1
grpcio              1.16.1
gym                 0.10.9
h5py                2.8.0
idna                2.8
imageio             2.4.1
inflection          0.3.1
Keras-Applications  1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.5
Kivy                1.10.1
Kivy-examples       1.10.1
Kivy-Garden         0.1.4
kivy.deps.glew      0.1.10
kivy.deps.gstreamer 0.1.13
kivy.deps.sdl2      0.1.18
kiwisolver          1.0.1
lxml                4.2.5
Markdown            3.0.1
matplotlib          3.0.2
more-itertools      4.3.0
mpl-finance         0.10.0
neat-python         0.92
numpy               1.15.4
pandas              0.23.4
pandas-datareader   0.7.0
Pillow              5.3.0
pip                 18.1
protobuf            3.6.1
pyglet              1.3.2
Pygments            2.3.1
pyparsing           2.3.0
pypiwin32           223
python-dateutil     2.7.5
pytz                2018.7
pywin32             224
Quandl              3.4.5
requests            2.21.0
scipy               1.1.0
setuptools          20.10.1
six                 1.11.0
tensorboard         1.12.0
tensorflow          1.12.0
termcolor           1.1.0
urllib3             1.24.1
virtualenv          16.1.0
Werkzeug            0.14.1
wheel               0.32.3
wrapt               1.10.11
```

### Log

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-12-23_1.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.1
[INFO   ] Python: v3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 NVIDIA 385.54'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'4.50 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\listview.py line 845.Called from C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py line 582 by _apply_rule().
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\simplelistadapter.py line 49.Called from C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\listview.py line 859 by __init__().
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\adapter.py line 111.Called from C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\simplelistadapter.py line 55 by __init__().
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\abstractview.py line 42.Called from C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\listview.py line 865 by __init__().
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\listadapter.py line 185.Called from D:\Documents\PersonalProjects\LineRiderBeautifier\KivyTests\kivyTest5\studentdb.kv line 49 by <module>().
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\adapter.py line 111.Called from C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\listadapter.py line 186 by __init__().
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[WARNING] Call to deprecated function __init__ in C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\selectableview.py line 38.Called from C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\listview.py line 593 by __init__().
[INFO   ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:\Documents\PersonalProjects\LineRiderBeautifier\KivyTests\kivyTest5\main.py", line 28, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     dbApp.run()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 799, in run
[WARNING] stderr:     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 596, in load_kv
[WARNING] stderr:     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
[WARNING] stderr:     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 368, in load_string
[WARNING] stderr:     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 392, in __init__
[WARNING] stderr:     self.parse(content)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 498, in parse
[WARNING] stderr:     self.execute_directives()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 462, in execute_directives
[WARNING] stderr:     mod = __import__(package)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:\Documents\PersonalProjects\LineRiderBeautifier\KivyTests\kivyTest5\main.py", line 28, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     dbApp.run()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
[WARNING] stderr:     runTouchApp()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
[WARNING] stderr:     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
[WARNING] stderr:     self._mainloop()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
[WARNING] stderr:     EventLoop.idle()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 340, in idle
[WARNING] stderr:     self.dispatch_input()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
[WARNING] stderr:     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 231, in post_dispatch_input
[WARNING] stderr:     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1360, in on_motion
[WARNING] stderr:     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1376, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
[WARNING] stderr:     self.dispatch('on_press')
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
[WARNING] stderr:   File "C:\Users\Daniel Warfield\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
[WARNING] stderr:     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "D:\Documents\PersonalProjects\LineRiderBeautifier\KivyTests\kivyTest5\studentdb.kv", line 34, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     on_press: root.submit_student()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
[WARNING] stderr: AttributeError: 'StudentDB' object has no attribute 'submit_student'
```

Comment: Not sure if i can reproduce your issue, it might be related to your platform, please see this video for comparison https://youtu.be/RYk-GQtBi9k

Comment: Just tested this on Linux and that isn't the behaviour, the scaling is dynamic. Are you using Windows? And presumably your Kivy installation is up to date?

Comment: I am using windows. I added the full results of pip list to the question. If I recall correctly, the kivy install is dependent on things which dont have kivy in the name? I added the whole pip list to be safe. Also, thank you guys so much for showing interest.

Comment: Yeah, I think everything is up to date

Comment: Can you post the log from when you run your app?

Comment: done and done..